# MIPS Calculate machine encoding of a jump instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I was wondering how I would calculate the machine encoding of a jump instruction.

Let's say I have 
 
j       foo
 
at address 0x00400000
 
Now, what if foo is at adress 0x0040002c. How would I then find the machine encoding of the jump instruction?

[0x00400000] j     foo
 
...
 
[0x0040002c] foo:   
 
Found some guide on Youtube saying it would be something like
((400000+4) - 40002c)/4 
 
But jump has the op-code 2, which I don't get with that calculation.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`J` has opcode 2, and is encoded as:

```
---------------------------
| opcode |     target     |
---------------------------
 6 bits       26 bits
```

Hence, the instruction word should be `(2 << 26) | target`.
Now, `J` and `JAL` are not PC-relative, but PC-region-relative. That is, `target` is the distance *in words* to the target address from the beginning of the 256MB region that you're currently executing in. The 256MB region in which 0x00400000 is located begins at 0x00000000. So `target` would be encoded as `(0x0040002c - 0x00000000) >> 2` == `0x0010000B`. That gives you the instruction word `(2 << 26) | 0x0010000B` == `0x0810000B`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Michael. I read somewhere about shifting left 2 bits, so that does make sense. However, are we really allowed to just add the Opcode as we choose? It seems a bit too good to be true, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you mean by _"just [adding] the Opcode as we choose"_. The opcode for `J` is 2 and it needs to be placed in bits 31:26 of the instruction word. That's pretty specific.